# MySQL select closest match within a subset of MySQL results

Tags: mysql, match, subset, greatest-n-per-group, closest

Suppose I have the following MySQL (InnoDB) table:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                          table "taskList"                         |
+----+------------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
| ID | TaskName         | Category | Date_time           | Priority |
+----+------------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
| 1  | cleanup          |   system | 2019-06-02 03:30:00 |        5 |
+----+------------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
| 2  | create_user      |   system | 2019-03-23 11:56:10 |        5 |
+----+------------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
| 3  | send_invoice     |   system | 2019-03-23 11:56:17 |        6 |
+----+------------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
| 4  | perform_selftest |   system | 2019-06-25 06:54:11 |        1 |
+----+------------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
| 5  | add_destination  |      map | 2019-02-15 16:21:04 |        2 |
+----+------------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
| 6  | verify_VIN       |  chassis | 2019-01-04 09:35:49 |        5 |
+----+------------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
```

I want to write a query selecting any records that match all of the following conditions (note that values between quotes are examples and will be parameterized in real world):

- Category 'system'
- Date_time between '2019-01-01' and '2019-07-01'
- having the highest Priority in this subset, closest to '2' (2 itself is allowed, but not anything higher, like 1)

In this case, there are 4 records matching the first two conditions. But of those 4, only 2 match the condition for Priority. So here records #1 and #2 (and only those) should be returned.



By searching this website I've written the following query which seems to work, but it's quite ugly and I have a feeling that it could be more efficient in terms of performance:

```
SELECT * FROM taskList
WHERE category='system'
AND (Date_time BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-07-01') 
AND Priority=(
   SELECT MIN(Priority) FROM taskList
   WHERE category='system'
   AND (Date_time BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-07-01') 
   AND Priority >= 2
)
ORDER BY Date_time DESC
```

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks, I've completely rewritten my post to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query, that uses a correlated subquery for filtering, seems to properly fit your use case, and should have pretty good performance, especially with an index on `(category, Date_time, Priority)`.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can also try and use `rank()`. This gives you a more concise query (you would need to compare performance against your original query):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT 
            t.* ,
            RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY category ORDER BY Priority) rn
        FROM taskList t
        WHERE 
            Category = 'system'
            AND Date_time BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-07-01') 
            AND Priority >= 2
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

NB: I added the `Category` to the rank partition, in case you ever need to make the query take in account more than one category.

Comment: Wow, this looks a lot cleaner and works really well! I had to make 2 slight modifications though: 1. you missed a '(' right before Date_time in the WHERE-clause of the inner SELECT, 2. I had to give the entire inner SELECT an alias to prevent Error 1248: "Every derived table must have its own alias". Would you advise an index here too?

Comment: @TonyTwoclicks: yes sorry I forgot the table alias, just added it. I am unsure about the index; possibly, the same index I recommended could help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, because the DDLs were not provided:

```
SELECT x.columns
     , x.you
     , x.actually
     , x.want
  FROM taskList x
  LEFT
  JOIN tasklist y
    ON y.category = x.category
   AND y.date_time = x.date_time
   AND y.priority < 2
 WHERE x.category='system'
   AND x.date_time BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-07-01'
   AND y.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm quite new to MySQL so forgive me for trying to wrap my head around your solution. Regarding the priority, what I think your solution does is that it excludes all records having a priority < 2 in table y, correct? If so, that would leave the records with priority >= 2. But what I want is to leave only the records with the closest (in other words: 'next highest') available priority starting from 2. So either 2, or 3, or 4, etc. In my example priority 5 is closest (or next highest) to 2, so that should leave only records #1 and #2.

Comment: Well, if you provide CREATE and INSERT statements (and a formatted, desired result), I might amend my answer!